# Django. Display data with Ajax

Tags: ajax, django

I have a list of my all posts:

```
def posts_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('posts.html', {'posts':posts},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in template:

```
{% for p in posts %}
    {{ p.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I want post  after clicking on its name shows **box(div)** with all information about this post(`Post` model: `name, content, date, author`)

How to do it using jquery(ajax)?

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Why dont you just post `id` of model instance and retrive it on a view? What is the need to store all field values on a template?

Comment: This is an abstract example. I want to learn jQuery/Ajax with Django. I need this example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add an additional view:

new view:

```
def post_content(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id = post_id)
    return render_to_response('post_info.html', {'post':post},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You'll need to create a post_info.html that gives more information about a post.

in your posts template:

```
{% for p in posts %}
     <span data-url='{% url post_content post_id=p.id %}' class='post'>{{ p.name }}<span class='more_info'></span></span>
{% endfor %}
```

then you'd have the following Javascript (using Jquery in this example)

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('.post').on('click', function() {
    var span = $(this);
    $.ajax({
     url: span.attr('data-url')
    }).done(function(data) {
         span.find('.more_info').html(data);
     });
});
});
```

This will replace the contents of the span with class more_info with the data from the server.

**Edit**: You'll also need to add something to your `urls.py` file, with `name= "post_content"` set.

Comment: Thank you. If I try I have error: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'post_id=p.id' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Ok: url(r'^post_content/$', 'post.views.post_content'), This error is still (Sorry for the constant questions). Do I need 2 arguments in this urls conf(post_id)?

Comment: You'd something more like `url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/post_content/$', 'post.views.post_content', name='post_content'),`

Comment: This error is still :( - Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'post_id=p.id' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: oops, it looks like you might have the code from the template wrong. you should have `data-url='{% url post_content post_id=p.id %}'`

Comment: Thanks. Now I have: http://dpaste.com/811692/ but still not working. I'm sorry for the trouble

Comment: Switch out the javascript that you have with the one I made in my last edit

Answer (score 1):

template.html:

```
{% for p in posts %}
    <div class="container"
        data-name="{{ p.name }}"
        data-content="{{ p.content }}">
        {{ p.name }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.container').click(function(event){
        var name = $(event.target).attr('data-name');
        var content = $(event.target).attr('data-content');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/test/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'name': name,
                'content':content
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Load was performed.');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, I store model fields as element attributes (`data-name=""`, ...). They can be retrieved with `.attr()` javascript method.

Then I bind click event for all divs with `class="container"`. On click script retrieves previously stored data and make ajax-request. Ajax calls are described in [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Code have not been tested, so I can not be sure in it efficiency.

**If I did not understand your goal correctly, let me know**